# Splitting a text column's row into multiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, nlp, text-processing

I have a dataset like this :
[how the dataset looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMsQz.png)

What I want is to divide the status information column with the names in it to create new columns one for the names present and another for their respective comments and then fill the rest of the columns accordingly, something like this:

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmQnR.png)

I am able to clean the text of punctuations and numbers and create a dictionary from the status information column with names as key and comments as values, but it still show the whole staement with all the names.

Here is the code I tried so far:

```
names = ['tom','robin']
months = ['jan','feb','mar','apr','may', 'jun','jul','aug','sep','oct','nov','dec',
          'january','february','march','april','june','july','august','september',
'october','november','december']


a = data['Status information'][3].lower()
b = [char for char in a if char not in string.digits]
b = ''.join(b)

for i in months:
    if b.find(i) != -1:
        b= b.replace(i,' ')

for i in string.punctuation:
    if b.find(i) != -1:
        b= b.replace(i,' ')
x={} 
for i in names:
    if b.find(i) != -1:
        x[i] = b.split(i)
        
print(b)
print(x)
```

Output:

```
tom  i want only server    robin cal busy    robin reg for server
{'tom': ['   ', '  i want only server    robin cal busy    robin reg for server'], 
'robin': ['   tom  i want only server    ', ' cal busy    ', ' reg for server']}
```

Comment: Can you add code that you have tried?

Comment: I just shared part of the code I tried

Comment: Is this even possible ???